# What is the most appropriate GUI Testing Tool for MS Dynamix CRM hybrid application?

Tags: testing, automation, functional-testing

I have been recently assigned as a tester on a web app that integrates with Microsoft Dynamix CRM.

There are a lot of repetitive testing tasks that could be automated to accelarate the testing effort.

I proposed this to my boss and said that I can start hacking together some watir scripts. However, he wants me to do more research (he is happy to invest the cash if there is something out there that can save us time - he is heavily attached to the idea of there being some kind of record and playback tool out there that cranks out robust scripts but I am not convinced).

This is my tool experience so far:

- webdriver (Python)
- watir-webdriver (just a dabble for an    interview)
- TestComplete (small suite of tests for a webapp in    2011)
- QTP (in 2009)

Can someone please recommend some tools for me? I don't really know where to start.

It sounds like

- Selenium / Webdriver is widely used, widely supported and a good price (free :) )
- "Telerik TestStudio" is quite popular but seems like overkill for what I want to do
- "QTP" is unreliable and overpriced.
- "TestComplete" has some scattered support.

Since I'm already handy with Ruby, I am leaning towards running with the Watir option. Does this seem like a reasonable course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to go with the Open Source solutions: either Watir or Selenium. Both should work, then it depends on your liking. Personally I use [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/) with its [selenium Library](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/#readme) and it works very well and has quite a dynamic community.

Note that you should also consider if you can do part of your testing bellow the UI. You could probably do some tests on the API offered by Dynamix and used by your web app. That would be quicker and more robust.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend selenium-webdriver. As you said it's widely used, widely supported and good price (free). As you aleady know Ruby you can write tests on ruby using selenium-webdriver.